# Are Vue component slots not considered children?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Lets say that I have a parent component, Tabs, which takes in child Tab Components as slots.

So the setup is like this:

**Tabs (Parent)**

```
<div>
  <slot name="tabChild">
</div>
```

**Tab (Child)**

```
<div>
  Tab {{name}}
</div>
```

**MyApp**

```
<Tabs>
   <Tab slot="tabChild" name="1" ></Tab>
   <Tab slot="tabChild" name="1" ></Tab>
</Tabs>
```

However, in the Tabs (Parent) component, when I try to programmatically access its children, like this:

**Tabs Component**

```
mounted(){
  let childTabs = this.$children  //this is empty?? 
  childTabs = this.$slots //this is correctly the child Tab Components
}
```

Moreover, in the Tab (Child) component, when I try to access its parent, which I thought was the Tabs component (since they are slotted within it), it is not:

**Tab Component**

```
mounted(){
   let parentTab = this.$parent //this is MyApp (grandfather), NOT Tabs
}
```

Why are the tab child components slotted within the greater Tabs component not its children?

Answer (score 0):

Well, [`$parent`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-parent) will always refer to the "direct" parent/wrapper a particular component is nested inside, so it's not quite reliable when the need to refer to the "root" parent arises.

Here are some good excerpts from the official docs:

1. In most cases, reaching into the parent makes your application more difficult to debug and understand, especially if you mutate data in the parent. When looking at that component later, it will be very difficult to figure out where that mutation came from. [[1]](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Parent-Component-Instance)
2. Use `$parent` and `$children` sparingly as they mostly serve as an escape-hatch. Prefer using props and events for parent-child communication. [[2]](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#parent)
3. Implicit parent-child communication: Props and events should be preferred for parent-child component communication, instead of `this.$parent` or mutating props.
   An ideal Vue application is **props down, events up**. Sticking to this convention makes your components much easier to understand. [[3]](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Implicit-parent-child-communication-use-with-caution)
4. Unfortunately, using the `$parent` property didn’t scale well to more deeply nested components. That’s where **dependency injection** can be useful, using two new instance options: `provide` and `inject`. [[4]](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Dependency-Injection)

---

Here's a quick example that sort of demonstrates the above recommendations:

```js
const Parent = Vue.extend({
  template: `
    <ul :style="{ columnCount: colCount }">
      <slot></slot>
    </ul>
  `,

  provide() {
    return {
      biologicalParent: this
    }
  },

  props: ['value', 'colCount', 'message'],
  
  methods: {
    sayIt() {
      const 
        num = this.$children.indexOf(this.value) + 1,
        
        message = [
          `I am child no. ${num}`,
          `among ${this.$children.length} of my siblings`,
          `in ${this.colCount} different lineages.`
        ]
        .join(' ');

      this.$emit('update:message', message);
    }
  },
  
  watch: {
    value: 'sayIt'
  }
});

const Child = Vue.extend({
  template: `<li v-text="name" @click="setChild"></li>`,

  props: ['name'],

  inject: ['biologicalParent'],

  methods: {
    setChild() {
      this.biologicalParent.$emit('input', this);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',

  data: () => ({
    lineage: 3,
    childCount: 10,
    message: 'Click on a child for the associated message.',
    lastChild: undefined
  }),

  components: {
    Parent,
    Child
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  width: 4em;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.message {
  background-color: beige;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Child count:</td>
      <td><input type="number" v-model="childCount" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Lineage:</td>
      <td><input type="number" v-model="lineage" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <parent 
    v-model="lastChild" 
    :col-count="lineage"
    :message.sync="message">
    <child 
      v-for="(n, i) of Array.apply(null, {length: childCount})" 
      :key="i" 
      :name="`child #${i+1}`">
    </child>
  </parent>

  <p class="message">{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

The `provide` options allows us to specify the `data` or `methods` we want to **provide** to descendant components. In the above example, that's the `Parent` instance.
Notice how the `Child` index/number is evaluated at runtime (when clicked) instead of compile time (rendering phase).

Comment: Isnt the 'Tabs' component the direct parent of the 'Tab' components? Thus, shouldnt $this.parent from the 'Tab' component return the 'Tabs' component?